# How to compute a polynomial derivative?

Tags: c, function, derivative

I am trying to write a function for calculating the derivative of a polynomial function. `degr` is the degree of the polynomial, `arr` is the array that contains the coefficients of the polynomial. I want to calculate the derivative at point `t`.

Below is my attempt, but it always returns `0`. I do not understand what is wrong.

```
float derv(int degr,int arr[],float t)
{
  int i,n;
  float sum=0;
  float arr2[degr+1];

  for (i=0;i<degr+1;i++) {
    arr[i]=(arr[i]*(i+1)); 
  } 
  degr=degr-1;
  for (i=0;i<degr+1;i++)
  {
     arr2[i] = (pow(t,degr-i)*arr[i]);
  }

  for(n=0;n<degr+1;n++)
  {
    sum = sum + arr2[n];
  } 
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Also, have you tried adding print statements (or using a debugger) to inspect the values of intermediate values?

Comment: Also, you'd better do it numerically...

Comment: where is lt declared...? edit: ah, formatting fixed...

Comment: yes actually this is just function part of my program.But rest of program working good.But from this function sum returns as Zero

Comment: -1 poorly written question...

Comment: `arr*(i+1)` that looks sketchy...

Comment: A couple of rules - name variables by the thing you save into them (not `arr2`!), don't initialize them long before you use them for the first time (`sum = 0`). Then your code will be readable and you will probably see the error immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some assumptions. If the polynomial looks like this:

```
         degr
        .---
p(x) =   >     arr[i] * pow(x, i)
        `---
         i=0
```

Then, the derivative would be obtained by:

```
           degr
d         .---
-- p(x) =  >    i * arr[i] * pow(x, i-1)
dx        `---
           i=1
```

You should be able to compute this with a loop similar to [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

For your program, you are processing it in several loops, which is unnecessary. But, your first loop is trying to recompute the coefficients. The first coefficient is a constant, so it should be recomputed to zero when the derivative is applied. Instead, you are multiplying by `(i+1)`. Just multiply by `i` instead.

In your second loop, you understand that the degree has been reduced, but since the first term is 0, you do not have to decrement the `degr` variable. You should start the loop from index `1`. Within the body of the for loop itself, the `pow` computation should raise to the `i-1` power.

In your `sum` calculation loop, also start from index `1`.

You should be able to see how the changes I suggested to you came straight from the formula I provided above.

Note, since you modify the array that represents the polynomial, you cannot call the function again to compute the derivative for a different value. You can fix this by modifying the first loop so that the coefficients get stored in `arr2` instead, and then changing the second loop so that you are obtaining the coefficients from `arr2`. Now, you can declare your input array to be constant in your `derv` function.

The code with my suggested changes looks like:

```
float derv(int degr,const int arr[],float t)
{
  int i,n;
  float sum=0;
  float arr2[degr+1];

  for (i=0;i<degr+1;i++) {
    arr2[i]=(arr[i]*i);
  }
  for (i=1;i<degr+1;i++)
  {
     arr2[i] = (pow(t,i-1)*arr2[i]);
  }

  for(n=1;n<degr+1;n++)
  {
    sum = sum + arr2[n];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The OP does not seem to know what the formula for the derivative is, because it is being computed incorrectly. Regards

Comment: I imagine the OP knows the maths behind evaluating a polynomial derivative (the code wouldn't look *almost* correct if they didn't).  But the question is what is wrong with the code?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Updated the answer with specific fixes to the code. Regards